# php-fpm stuck at state: Finishing

Tags: php-fpm

The site use nginx+php-fpm. Today, accessing some pages returns 502 state in a few seconds (different from 502 caused by php script timeout), while other pages stay in service.

Status page of php-fpm shows all processes are `active`, but they're all stucked in `State: finishing`, and load of server is low.

```
pid:                  12775
state:                Finishing
start time:           18/May/2013:16:50:27 +0800
start since:          755
requests:             59
request duration:     743543095
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /data/webserver/index.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0
```

I'm wondering why this happened, although it becomes well after I restart the `php-fpm`.

Comment: Hi Haocheng! I was having the same problem, some pages got stuck in finishing state, did you ever fix this?

Comment: @BetoAveiga For me, it comes to be that the function registered by `register_shutdown_function` was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by a long running function registered in `fastcgi_finish_request()`, after a long investigation. FYI if you're looking for the answer.